# how to solve $\log{x}=cx^4$ for $x$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, gre-exam

I was wondering if there is a general solution for this form of equations:
$$\log{x}=cx^4$$

Tried: $$ x = e^{cx^4}\\
xe^{-cx^4}=1$$

Comment: There isn't even a simple closed form for $\log x = cx$. You can solve it numerically, however.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\log x/x^4$ has derivative $\frac{1-4\log x}{x^5}$, so the maximum real value for $c$ is at $x=e^{1/4}$, which is a maximum value of $c=\frac{1}{4e}$.

This is one of those equations that requires the [Lambert W-function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Raise your last equation to the fourth power, then multiply by $-4c$ and you get:

$$-4cx^4e^{-4cx^4}=-4c$$

Then apply the Lambert W-function and you get:

$$-4cx^4=W(-4c)$$

Or $$x=\left(\frac{W(-4c)}{-4c}\right)^{1/4}$$

There are actually two real values of $W(-4c)$ when $0<c<\frac{1}{4e}$. See the linked article for details about this.

Comment: Some $c$ yield two real solutions, which you can see from graphing the two sides of OP's original equation. Can you extend this to account for both?

Comment: @alex.jordan: the Lambert-W function is a branched function. In this case, two of the branches give real values.

Comment: Yes, you have to deal with the two real branches on $(-1/e,0)$, which the Wikipedia article covers somewhat.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, I just meant to suggest to Thomas to add discussion of this to his answer. +1 for the answer either way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get an equivalent answer in terms of Lambert W function:
\begin{align}
\log(x) &= c x^4 \\
\log(x) x^{-4} &= c \\
\log(x^{-4}) x^{-4} &= -4c \\
\log(x^{-4}) \mathrm{e}^{\log(x^{-4})} &= -4c \\
\log(x^{-4}) &= W(-4c) \\
\log(x) &= -\frac{1}{4}W(-4c) \\
x &= \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{4}W(-4c)}
\end{align}

A real solution for $c<\frac{1}{4\mathrm{e}}$
is $x = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{4}W_{0}(-4c)}$,
a second real solution for $0<c<\frac{1}{4\mathrm{e}}$
is $x = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{4}W_{-1}(-4c)}$.
Some software systems that support $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$ 
are mentioned in  [Lambert W function:Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Software),
for example
`gsl_sf_lambert_W0` and `gsl_sf_lambert_Wm1` 
functions from the GNU Scientific Library.