# GRE Subject question $\log x=c x^4$

Tags: calculus, gre-exam

For what positive value of $c$ does the equation $\log x=cx^4$ have exactly one real solution for $x$?.  Thank you.

Comment: hint: if there is only 1 solution, the graphs are tangent in the intersection. This gives you a second equation.

Comment: This has been asked before [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523319/log-x-cx4-has-only-one-root-find-c) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967374/how-to-solve-logx-cx4-for-x).

Answer (score 0):

Hint write it as $\frac {log (x)}{x^4} =c $ then notice values at $1,\infty $ they are $0$ value at infinity can be found out using limits.Thus using rolles theorem there is altleast $1 x $ for which $f'(d)=0$ for $d\in (0,\infty)$ thus you can find the $d $